# Can't clone, can SSH. "Permission denied (publickey)."

Tags: windows, git, ssh, git-credential-manager

I cannot clone or push to a repository on my server.

I have a bare repo that is located is a directory `user@host` in directory `home/user/test.git` that I am trying to access via `git clone`. I used `ssh-add <pathtokey>` to add my ssh key. It asked me for the passphrase.  I can then `ssh user@host` successfully.

However if I then try to `git clone ssh://user@host/~/test.git` I get:

```
Cloning into 'test'...
user@host: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

also tried

- `git clone ssh://user@host/home/user/test.git`
- `git clone user@host:home/user/test.git`
- `git clone user@host:/home/user/test.git`

with the same result

I am guessing the git credential manager isn't picking up the keys?

On the server `/var/auth/log` says
`Feb 20 02:25:36 xxxxx sshd[24674]: Connection closed by authenticating user XXXX x.x.x.x port 56433 [preauth]`

- Git version: `git version 2.30.1.windows.1`
- Git Credential Manager: `Git Credential Manager version 2.0.318-beta+44acfafa98 (Windows, .NET Framework 4.0.30319.42000)`
- `git config -l` reports `credential.helper=manager-core`
- Tried both `PowerShell` and `git bash` shells, same result
- `user` has read, execute permissions to the repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The git credential manager is only involved for caching credentials (username/password) for HTTPS URL, not SSH.
Only the ssh-agent could be involved, for caching a possible passphrase, if the private key was defined with it.

I would try first using the full path, since `~` might not be interpreted by the remote shell, but the local (which has a different path for `~`):

```
git clone ssh://user@host/home/user/test.git
# or
git clone user@host:/home/user/test.git
```

If not, in a git bash session, type:

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -v'
git clone ...
```

The OP confirms [in the discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/51633980#51633980) it works in a bash session:

> In git bash, I started the `ssh-agent`,
> added the key there, then it worked.

Comment: Same result on the absolute path

Comment: @AdamV.Steele Do you have any environment variable starting with GIT_SSH? Is your private key a ppk one (putty) or an pem/openssh one (made with `ssh-keygen`)?

Comment: @AdamV.Steele I would also try `git clone user@host:/home/user/test.git`

Comment: I can `ssh` in just fine. Only git commands fail. I don't have any variables starting with `GIT_SSH`. Its an OpenSSH key

Comment: @AdamV.Steele OK. Do you confirm `git clone user@host:/home/user/test.git` also does not work?

Comment: @AdamV.Steele Note: this is `git clone user@host:/home/user/test.git`, *not* `git clone user@host:home/user/test.git`: the `:/` is important.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228980/discussion-between-vonc-and-adam-v-steele).

Answer (score 5):

To add to @VonC's response

In git-bash things work as normal.

The normal flow of starting the `ssh-agent` (via `eval 'ssh-agent'`
), adding the key via `ssh-add <path_to_key>` enables `git clone` to work.

In PowerShell Core, or Cmd, via Windows-Terminal more work is required

the `ssh-agent` starts automatically (assuming you previously started the `OpenSSH Authentication Agent` service), adding the key works, and you can `ssh` after this, but `git` commands do NOT work, initially, but if you do

```
git config --global core.sshCommand C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe
```

This will replace the (default) ssh that comes with git-for-windows with the Windows10 implementation.

After this it should work fine in things other than git-bash. Confirmed in Powershell-Core, Command Prompt

See also:
https://gist.github.com/danieldogeanu/16c61e9b80345c5837b9e5045a701c99

Comment: This definitely solved my problem, thanks!